# I Descriptor Length

Tags: universe

In UniVerse, I am trying to convert a ZIP+4 to just a 5 character ZIP. I have set the output length for my new field to 5 and it displays the ZIP in 5 characters, but I still have an issue when trying to filter by certain criteria (Example: ZIP = 36301). This query would not pull ZIPs with a PLUS4. Is there a way to limit the character length of an I-Desciptor. Currently, this is how I have for the I-desciptor:

```
TRANS(CUST,@ID,6,"X")
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have solved my issue with the following:

```
TRANS(CUST,@ID,6,"X");@1[1,5]
```

If anyone sees anything wrong with this, please let me know.

Comment: Looks fine. Just confirming that this dictionary item is on a file other than 'CUST'?